# Consider $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ which are iid and have common pdf $f(x | \theta) = e^{-x+\theta}$ $(x > \theta)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Consider $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ which are iid and have common pdf $f(x | \theta) = e^{-x+\theta}$ $(x > \theta)$. Why is $$\frac{f(x|\theta)}{f(y|\theta)} = \exp \left\{{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i-x_i)}\right\} \cdot \frac{I_{(0,\infty)} \mathbf{x}_{(1)}}{I_{(0,\infty)} \mathbf{y}_{(1)}}$$

where $\mathbf{x}_{(1)} = \min x_i$?

Can someone explain me the above equation (identity)? Using the definition $f(x|\theta) := \prod_i f(x_i|\theta)$, I don't see it.

Comment: Your $f(x|\theta)$ is not a valid pdf

Comment: Perhaps you meant $x>\theta$?

Comment: @Firebug Yes, you're right. Fixed that.

Comment: I would have expected to see $\theta$ in $ \dfrac{I_{(0,\infty)} \mathbf{x}_{(1)}}{I_{(0,\infty)} \mathbf{y}_{(1)}}$ - perhaps it should be  $\dfrac{I_{(\theta,\infty)} \mathbf{x}_{(1)}}{I_{(\theta,\infty)} \mathbf{y}_{(1)}}$.  It is related to your $x>\theta$ condition

Comment: Also fix the title of the Q, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your pdf as
$f(x) = e^{-x + \theta} \cdot I_{(\theta \, ;\, + \infty)}(x)$.

Then you can use two properties:
$$\prod_i I_{(\theta \, ;\, + \infty)}(x_i) = I_{(\theta \, ;\, + \infty)}(\min_i \{x_i\})$$

and
$$\prod_i e^{-x_i + \theta} = e^{-\sum_{i}(x_i - \theta)} \,.$$

This leads to $$f(x\mid\theta) = e^{-\sum_{i}(x_i - \theta)}I_{(\theta \, ;\, + \infty)}(\boldsymbol{x}_{(1)})$$
and thus
$$\frac{f(x\mid\theta)}{f(y\mid\theta)} = e^{\sum_{i}(y_i - x_i)}\frac{I_{(\theta \, ;\, + \infty)}(\boldsymbol{x}_{(1)})}{I_{(\theta \, ;\, + \infty)}(\boldsymbol{y}_{(1)})}\, .$$

I hope this helps.